# Need to change my domain name

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I recently set up a Gmail account for my new business. I purchased `@mybusinessnameone.com` but now I would like to change it to `@mybusinessnametwo.com` or keep both if they can feed together.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are talking about a "[Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/)" account.

Not clear if the first domain (conquerlogistics.com) has been associated with the account or not.  In either case, the procedure to do this is a bit lengthy to describe here.  See [Google Apps Help](http://support.google.com/a/?hl=en) for details.

Google Apps accounts allow you to define a "domain alias" (inside the "Domains" area of the Admin Console), which will allow you to simultaneously associate one or more additional domains (such as "conquer3pl.com").  See the [documentation](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295&topic=14592&ctx=topic) for details.